# Is "less" or "fewer" correct here?

Tags: grammar

Try to make **less** mistakes from now on

Try to make **fewer** mistakes from now on

According to my knowledge it should be less as it is used for uncountable nouns , whereas fewer mistakes is used for countable nouns, and we don't know the number of mistakes

Comment: You're confusing "countable" with "knowing the exact number". Whether a noun is countable or not is part of the definition of the word. A good dictionary, particularly a learner's dictionary will tell you that a word is countable or not. This is all you need to know to determine whether to use "less" or "fewer".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mistakes are countable. You don't need to know the exact number of items for a noun to be countable.

> Each class has fewer than twenty students.

The exact number of students is unknown, but students are still countable.

> The teacher led a review session so that the students would make fewer mistakes on their final exams than they did on their midterms.